# @ManyToMany compile issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've been working on my User - Role - Mapping issue for quite some time now, but i'm currently stuck at this issue:
 ***Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class:***

**User**

```
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Collection<Role> roles;
```

**Role**

```
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Collection<User> users;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "roles_privileges", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "privilege_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Collection<Privilege> privileges;
```

**Previleges**

```
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "privileges")
    private Collection<Role> roles;
```

I believe the issue is somewhere between the relations in the mapping structure. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Specify the datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "mappedBy" property in all of your "@ManyToMany" annotations.

**User**

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "users")
@JoinTable(name = "users_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private Collection<Role> roles;
```

**Role**

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
private Collection<User> users;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
@JoinTable(name = "roles_privileges", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "privilege_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private Collection<Privilege> privileges;
```